# Syntax error with regex function in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a simple piece of code for an html5 banner, it's for a specific ad serving platform, however there's an error when in runs in chrome.

The error is:
`index.html:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

I'm not exactly a whiz at reading this kind of regex code. Can anyone figure out what the issue is?

```
function getParameterByName(name){
    name=name.replace(/[\/, "\\[").replace(/[\]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + '=([^&#]*)"),results = regex.exec(location.search); return results === null ? "":decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var clickTAG = getParameterByName("clickTAG");
```

I found a very similar piece of code that does not throw an error:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
       results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results === null ? "" :
       decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }
```

The difference is in this line
`name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");`  - working
`name = name.replace(/[\/, "\\[").replace(/[\]/, "\\]");` - not working

What's the difference? What's the meaning of `[]` and adding an extra `]`?

Comment: I think you mixed up `'`s and `"`s in your strings.

Comment: It's not the replace what's not working, it's the new RegExp(). Take a look at my answer, just replace ' with ". Strings should be either with bot " " or both ' ', cannot use different

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character. For example, the string `"Here is a quotation mark: \""` would output `Here is a quotation mark: "` - The `\ ` tells the immediately following character to be treated as part of the string, rather than acknowledging its syntax representation You're escaping your closing /` in the first example.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in the code preview. It is obvious that there is something that is not terminated properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a problem with your first line of code, it does not have a closing / in it, and then 2nd line does not have correct enclosing string, try this code, it works

```
function getParameterByName(name){
    name=name.replace(/[\/]/, "\\[").replace(/\[\]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + '=([^&#]*)'),results = regex.exec(location.search); return results === null ? "":decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var clickTAG = getParameterByName("clickTAG");
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Replace  '  with  "  in your regex constructor

```
new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + '=([^&#]*)"),
```

------------------------------------------^ this character above arrow should be "

'=([^&#]*)"  this element is not in "  ", neither '  '.

From the code you posted:

```
new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + '=([^&#]*)") // your code
new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)") // working code
```

It's really easy to spot the difference